# sweet alert open animation disable

Tags: animation, alert, sweetalert

Am using sweet alert plugin, Even after turning setting option animation : false also I am getting sweet alert opening animation(fade in- fade out like) is coming. How to disable it.sweet alertsweet alert

Comment: Please explain more clearly.  For example, what platform is this?

Comment: @jerry  : I was using old sweet alert plugin that's why option **animation: false** was not working. That option is only available in sweet alert 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original sweet alert plugin is unsupported, I suggest you using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) plugin.

Migration is simple, here's the migration guide: [Migration from SweetAlert to SweetAlert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2)

Here's the example with SweetAlert2 and disabled animation:

```js
Swal.fire({
  icon: 'success',
  title: 'SweetAlert2 modal without animation',
  showClass: {
    backdrop: 'swal2-noanimation', // disable backdrop animation
    popup: '',                     // disable popup animation
    icon: ''                       // disable icon animation
  },
  hideClass: {
    popup: '',                     // disable popup fade-out animation
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Comment: yeah it solved , i was using old sweet alert. Thank you mate

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution to disable the animation.

If you want to remove the scale animation, add it to your main css file:

```
.swal-overlay--show-modal, .swal-modal {
    animation: none !important;
}
```

If you want to remove the opacity animation too, add this too:

```
.swal-overlay{
    transition: none !important;
}
```